# Getting data in Kubernetes pod before the container starts

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a python program that can control a Kubernetes cluster (from outside). During that program execution, it obtains a byte array.

I have full pod spec ready to be created.

I need to modify the pod spec (adding an init container) so that when the main container starts, there is a file somewhere with those exact bytes.

What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Is the file static? If so, you could mount a ConfigMap as a volume to the Python container without needing to use an initContainer (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume). If the file is dynamic, you'll need to store the file on a volume somewhere so that it's accessible to the Pod at runtime (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes). This approach should not need an initContainer either as your Python code can then access the file directly.

Comment: As I implied in the question (I specifically spoke about a byte array), the data is not known beforehand. I have troubles dynamically putting files on volumes. That's what this question is about. This seems like a trivial operation, but neither Docker nor Kubernetes seem to support that. You need a running Pod with some specific executables installed on it to perform `kuberctl cp`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to run a Python script that will extract or derive a byte array from somewhere before your Pod starts, and writes this byte array to a file for your actual application to read from when running inside the Pod.

I can see 2 ways to achieve this:

- Slightly modify your Docker image to run your script as an entrypoint and then running your application (command: & args: in your Pod spec). You would ship both together and won't need an initContainer.
- Or as you were tending for: use a combination of initContainer and Volumes

For the later:

```
template:
  spec:
    volumes:
    - name: byte-array
      emptyDir: {}
    initContainers:
        - name: byte-array-generator
          image: your/init-image:latest
          command: ["/usr/bin/python", "byte_array_generator.py"]
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /my/byte-array/
              name: byte-array
    containers:
    - name: application
      image: your/actual-app:latest
      volumeMounts:
        - name: byte-array
          mountPath: /byte-array/
```

I condensed all 3 parts:

- 1 empty volume definition used to pass over the file
- 1 initContainer with your script generating the byte array and writing it to disk in let's say /my/byte-array/bytearray.bin (where the volume has been mounted)
- 1 actual container running your application and reading the byte array from /byte-array/bytearray.bin (where the volume has been mounted)

One important note from there you also need to take into consideration is: if you mount your volume on a pre-existing folder with actual files, they will all "overwritten" by your volume. The source will take the destination's place.
You might be able to prevent that using `subPath` but I never tried with this way, I only know it works if you mount ConfigMaps as volumes.

***Edit***: the answer to your comment is too long

Outside the container or outside the Kubernetes cluster ? Maybe there is a misconception, so just in case: an initContainer doesn't have to use the same image as your Pod's. You could even load your script as a ConfigMap and mount it into the initContainer using Python base image to run it if you want...

But if really your script has to be running outside of the cluster and send a file enabling your Pod to start, I'd suggest you add a logic to your byte generation that will output it to a file taking the Pod hostname for example (from Kubernetes API), and scp it to the Kubernetes node running it (pulled from Kubernetes API too) into a know destination. Just define a folder on **each** of your nodes, like `/var/data/your_app/` and mount it on all your pods.

```
volumes:
  - hostPath:
       path: /var/data/your_app
      type: Directory
    name: bite-arrays
```

then mount `bite-arrays` wherever you want in whatever container needs to read it by reusing its hostname (to allow you to scale if necessary).
Since you said your script is controlling the cluster, I assume it's already talking to Kubernetes' API... You might also want to create a logic to cleanup left-overs...

Or maybe we got it all wrong and somehow your script is also generating and applying the Pod spec on the fly, which in this case could just be solved by an environment variable or a ConfigMap shipped alongside...

**Pod spec:**

```
volumes:
  - name: byte-array
    configMap:
      name: your-app-bytes

volumeMounts:
  - name: byte-array
    mountPath: /data/your-app/byte-array
    readOnly: true
    subPath: byte-array
```

**ConfigMap:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: your-app-bytes
data:
  byte-array: |-
    WHATEVERBYTESAREGENERATEDHERE
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the script is *outside* of the container. This script generates the data blob (using outside info) and starts the pod (locked down container).

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an opinion question/answer.

If it happens that your python script generates specific bytes I would go with an `initContainer` with a volume. Something like this:

```
initContainers:
- name: init-container
  image: container:version
  command: [ 'your-python.py' ]
  volumeMounts:
  - name: conf
    mountPath: /mnt/conf.d
containers:
- name: app-container
  image: container:version
  command: [ 'your-actual-app' ]
  volumeMounts:
  - name: conf
    mountPath: /mnt/conf.d
```

If your bytes are straight UTF-8 characters, for example, it's easier to just use a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

Comment: >"If it happens that your python script generates specific bytes"  - Unfortunately that's not the case. As I stated in my question, the data comes from outside (e.g. passed by user to our host python program). I know about init containers and use them, but reading/writing arbitrary data from/to volume is still hard.